# How to continue yum download while not deleting existing cache?

Tags: package-management, yum

I'm trying to upgrade my SL7.0 VM to 7.4 using yum. There are 1.3GB of packages that need to be downloaded but my modem can only handle about 300-400MB per day (and I have to disconnect it every midnight to enable all-day internet access).

Initially I thought that using `yum update --downloadonly` after network disconnects could resume the downloading. However, the second time I used this command it started downloading all the packages again ignoring the cache.

How should I proceed?

**Update:** just now I cleaned the cache with `yum clean all` and I'm going to investigate whether <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> the `yum` process before disconnecting the modem solves the problem.

Comment: What did you already try to do? (It would be nice when also the title starts with a capital)

Comment: I guess the only way to do it is to do a local install through a script that lists the rpms downloaded locally and then installs them. You can then repeat the process the next day.

Comment: @ProBackup I knew immediately that `yum update` wouldn't work for this task, so appending --downloadonly was the first thing I did. Then I was planning to do a local install from the cache when that finished.

Comment: Idea: Add some (firewall/router?) rule that shapes network traffic from the server that yum connects to, to an acceptable low level that downloads no more then 300-400MB per day. 350MiB is approximately equal to 4289 bytes per second, or 4.188 kilobyte per second. Then you might end up with a set-and-forget solution without manual interference to stop and start.